# JS сортировка объекта по нескольким полям

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка, объекты

```
[{
    user_name: 'Техномаркет - Магазин Оригинальных Смартфонов',
    user_id: '15fa675e3904eeb007693ce1440e01a4',
    title: 'AirPods Pro',
    group_count: 255
  },
  {
    user_name: 'MATAPPLE',
    user_id: 'ca5bf44f8c7599d1b948737cb7436209',
    title: 'Airpods 2 (новые, ростест, бонус чехол)',
    group_count: 215
  },
  {
    user_name: 'MATAPPLE',
    user_id: 'ca5bf44f8c7599d1b948737cb7436209',
    title: 'Airpods Pro (Lyx, новые, ростест)',
    group_count: 114
  },
  {
    user_name: 'AirStore - оригинальная техника',
    user_id: 'f055d21122ce650fa02069b4764879ae',
    title: 'AirPods 1/2/pro левый правый наушник кейс оригинал',
    group_count: 109
  },
  {
    user_name: 'Техномаркет - Магазин Оригинальных Смартфонов',
    user_id: '15fa675e3904eeb007693ce1440e01a4',
    title: 'AirPods Pro версия 2023 года, гарантия',
    group_count: 109
  }]
```

Подскажите как отсортировать? Сортировка по 'group_count' и 'user_id'.   После сортировки должны получить:

```
      [{
        user_name: 'Техномаркет - Магазин Оригинальных Смартфонов',
        user_id: '15fa675e3904eeb007693ce1440e01a4',
        title: 'AirPods Pro',
        group_count: 255
      },
      {
        user_name: 'Техномаркет - Магазин Оригинальных Смартфонов',
        user_id: '15fa675e3904eeb007693ce1440e01a4',
        title: 'AirPods Pro версия 2023 года, гарантия',
        group_count: 109
      },
      {
        user_name: 'MATAPPLE',
        user_id: 'ca5bf44f8c7599d1b948737cb7436209',
        title: 'Airpods 2 (новые, ростест, бонус чехол)',
        group_count: 215
      },
      {
        user_name: 'MATAPPLE',
        user_id: 'ca5bf44f8c7599d1b948737cb7436209',
        title: 'Airpods Pro (Lyx, новые, ростест)',
        group_count: 114
      },
      {
        user_name: 'AirStore - оригинальная техника',
        user_id: 'f055d21122ce650fa02069b4764879ae',
        title: 'AirPods 1/2/pro левый правый наушник кейс оригинал',
        group_count: 109
      }]
```

Comment: В чем возникли сложности? Из указанных полей, кто главнее? Сортировка по убыванию или возрастанию?

Comment: Воспользоваться методом [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). В метод передается функция с двумя аргументами `arr.sort((a,b) => {  //return результат сравнения; })`. Если объект `a` идет первым, нужно вернуть число <0, если вторым >0, для равных 0. В вашем случае нужно только составить правильные условия.